# How to determine a Config changed

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, configuration

While working with configurations, what is the best way to find out if the user changed something within the config.

I need this for determining if I shall display a MessageBox to ask for saving or not.

I have heard of the possibility of saving hashes and stuff.
But I am not sure about it.
Just creating a new Object out of UserInputs and comparing it to the one I loaded from drive obviously is not a solution...

Sure it can be done by comparing each value for each property new to old but since configs can get really huge this is not a clean solution.

So what is the most common and practical way to do this ?

Hint: I am saving my configs as XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have heard of the possibility of saving hashes and stuff.

This is your quickest and safest solution. You can produce either an MD5 or SHA and, whenever your config file changes, you can create a file called `"my.config.[SHA hash].sha"` or create a file called `"config.hashes"`:

```
<hashes>
   <hash file="my.config">[SHA hash]</hash>
</hashes>
```

In my case, I would store the file in JSON format:

```
[
   { file: "my.config", hash: "[SHA hash]" }
]

// or just...

{
   "my.config": "[SHA hash]"
}
```

Probably you'll want to take a look at [`FileSystemWatcher` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If I get you right here all I have to do is then take all the userInputs to my actual ConfigObject hash it and then compare it to the actual hash stored in my config file ?

Comment: @FeDe That's it. BTW, you can use a `FileSystemWatcher` to avoid a lot of coding. You just need to detect a file change and rehash it.